# How to get rid of -NONE- and *T*-i in ptb parse trees using nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, parse-tree

I process penn tree bank v2 trees and often encounter "service"-subtrees like these (and several other types)

[image]

I can manually add a lot of rules to refine nodes that I actually use further (parse with tags and tokens and without "oh, look there" links or "there must have been a node here" - just like those returned by Stanford parser), but I most often leave some of these service-nodes or huge gaps and "cropped branches" (like, if you remove those `-NONE-` nodes above, you'd have `SBAR` left with no children at all which is weird).

I wonder if I can remove everything except actual parses (words, tags, punctuation) from a the output of `from nltk.corpus import ptb; ptb.parsed_sents()` ones and for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete any subtree that only dominates traces. In the following, I iterate over subtrees but actually check their children; this makes it easy to delete an empty subtree by modifying the node that contains it.

```
for sub in some_tree.subtrees():
    for n, child in enumerate(sub):
        if isinstance(child, str):
            continue
        if all(leaf.startswith("*") for leaf in child.leaves()):
            del sub[n]  # Delete this child
```

I used `leaf.startswith("*")` as a simple criterion to detect traces. Replace it with your own as necessary.

**Edit:** Since you want to delete all nodes containing only subtrees labeled `-NONE-`, and each such subtree dominates exactly one leaf, use the following test:

```
    if len(list(child.subtrees(filter=lambda x:x.label()=='-NONE-')))==len(child.leaves()):
        del sub[n]
```

Comment: what about `-NONE-` things? the problem is that I don't know all sorts of  these service nodes; I have only presented a concrete example in question

Comment: If your criterion for deletion is to delete every `-NONE-` node and every higher node that becomes empty as a result, you should modify the criterion accordingly. If this tag always occurs with height 1, it's pretty easy: Delete any subtree that dominates as many `-NONE-` nodes as it has leaves.

Comment: thank you very much for a concrete answer, @alexis ! that is very useful, though, the problem I mentioned is little different; I was wondering if I could get rid of everything except parse itself, without knowing in advance what "everything else" is :) because it turned out there're bunch of these traces and co-indexes out there and if you remove some, others will remain. That is a very useful snippet for the beginning, though!

Comment: I'm not sure what your objection is: As far as I can see from the `treebank` corpus all traces are dominated by a `-NONE-` node, so the new criterion should delete all subtrees that contain nothing but traces. Anyway if the function you discovered does what you want, by all means use that. What it does is quite different from simply deleting trace-only subtrees, though.

Comment: Actually, your answer contains great technique worth being notices by itself: looking at leaves of all subtrees.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `@alexsis` answer below, now I know that those things are called traces and co-indexes. I found the following [implementation](https://github.com/wmaier/treetools/blob/457f224b111feb9c2be8501bfdfea22f61ddf26f/trees/transform.py#L461) of `def ptb_delete_traces(tree)` in the [`treetools`](https://github.com/wmaier/treetools) package.